# Error when deploying: proto.016-PtMumbai.michelson_v1.bad_stack

Tags: smart-contracts, ghostnet

**TezosOperationError: (permanent) proto.016-PtMumbai.michelson_v1.bad_stack**

Now getting this issue while deploying contract on ghostnet, whats the reason for this?

Comment: Please give more context. What tools did you use to build the script and try to originate the contract?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears with the sp.failwith in the code [here](https://smartpy.io/ide?cid=QmexSYW35uYi48X2eTzcEoaW5uDh25XpQSFNec62MrwWdx&k=0f90ed90627ecf0593bc), SmartPy team will investigate on that. What one can do is to remove the failwith and add a sp.verify before.

Also, its not needed to copy the code, one can create a different name for the variables and give this name in the function parameters.
Also simplified the second match_cons now [here](https://smartpy.io/ide?cid=QmQzwvFGstYsi8ZcQ6BPc8tESLF4YSgtHVax5X1VFBsNVb&k=d76f66140333d03688f6)